# Google play services api 17

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

Проблема заключается в том,что на api 22 всё работает хорошо,заходит собственно в профиль,а на api 17 жалуется на Google Play Services.
Объясните в чём может быть проблема?
Работаю с Firebase.

gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "by.ittech.test_chat"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на скриншоте сказано, что просто надо обновить гуглосервисы на устройстве/эмуляторе. вы используете 10.2.1, а установлены более старые

Comment: @DeKaNszn как собственно это делается на эмуляторе,подскажите

Comment: внезапно, но... как и на устройстве - надо всего-то тапнуть нотификации и в открывшемся Google Play нажать обновить. Я надеюсь вы эмулятор с Google Play используете?

Comment: @DeKaNszn я тапал по уведомлению,но, ба-бам,ничего не происходит. Было бы это так просто,вопрос бы не задавал)

Comment: Я не просто так упомянул про наличие Google Play на эмуляторе. Создайте, используя один из двух шаблонов, с нужным вам API level - https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG5Tb.png

Comment: @DeKaNszn Я создал новый эмулятор Nexus 5, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: Во времена, когда не было эмуляторов с гугл плей, просто понижали версию плей сервисов на время тестирования. Ну это так, совет на крайний случай.